# View.Gone inside adapter leaves space in onBindViewHolder

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-linearlayout, android-adapter

This is my onBindViewHolder method:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final mViewHolder h, int i) {
    final JSON data = jdata[i];

    if(data .getName() != null && data .getStatus() !=null) {
        h.textcontainer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                /*width*/ ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                /*height*/ ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                /*weight*/ 1.0f
        );
        h.textcontainer.setLayoutParams(params);
        h.title.setText(feed.getName());
    } else {
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                /*width*/ ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                /*height*/ ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                /*weight*/ 2
        );
        h.textcontainer.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        h.playerView.setLayoutParams(params);
    }
```

and this my XML:

```
 <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/videopost_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_parent_rounded_corner"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="2"

 >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/video_textcontainer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/feed_item_padding_left_right"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/feed_item_padding_left_right"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/feed_item_padding_top_bottom"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/feed_item_padding_top_bottom"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/video_title"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="@dimen/feed_item_profile_name"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="@color/background"
            android:paddingStart="@dimen/feed_item_profile_info_padd"
            android:paddingEnd="@dimen/feed_item_profile_info_padd"
            />

</LinearLayout>

        <com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.PlayerView
            android:id="@+id/exo_player_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:show_buffering="true"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            >

        </com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.PlayerView>
```

My Adapter has a textview in it, when the json data = null, I obviously want to hide that TextView without any spacing left, and when the data (title for the video) isn't null, I want to show the text.
The current codes hides the TextView, but leaves an empty space. If I delete the following two lines from the if-statemant:

```
     LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                /*width*/ ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                /*height*/ ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                /*weight*/ 1.0f
        );
        h.textcontainer.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Then there's no empty space left, but the TextView won't display if the data isn't empty. I'm pretty sure this is some stupid error somewhere, but I'm not able to find it. SOS :-)

Comment: Remove the weights and change your LinearLayout height to `wrap_content`.

Comment: Hide Visibility in else part which is in onBindViewHolder(). This will work.

Comment: @Rajnishsuryavanshi: check out my Edit

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you have two individual layouts `LinearLayout` and `PlayerView` sharing a weight sum of two (2) making it a 50:50 distribution. Whether the child view of the `LinearLayout` is gone the 50% space would still remain until it's given out.

Hence any time you need to hide textview/title completely and remove not-needed space, dynamically set the weight of `PlayerView` to two (2) and make the visibility of `LinearLayout` gone.

Comment: `weightSum` is explicitly intended to allow you to leave space behind when the total weights are less than the sum. If you _don't want_ this behavior, don't specify a `weightSum` in the first place.

Comment: @BenP. hey Ben, glad to see you again! I specified it to get rid of it, without the weight the behaviour doesn't change :( Offtopic: Have you seen my other question to the horizontal feed problem we've talked about [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57355881/positioning-views-inside-list).

Comment: @Giddy: look at my edit, it still doesn't work. maybe I should get rid of the weight sum as Ben P said?

Comment: @Los Kayos Yes probably for more concise approach remove weights entirely and make `PlayerView` height matchparent while the `LinearLayout` wrap_content. Nevertheless doing this you may want to specify a fixed height for the overall parent layout instead of using wrap_content.

Answer (score 0):

The LinearLayout around your TextView is redundant. You can simplify this to simply be a single LinearLayout with two children. Set the height to `wrap_content` and do not specify a `weightSum`. When the TextView's visibility is set to `GONE`, PlayerView will be the only visible child and your LinearLayout will match its size.

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/videopost_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_parent_rounded_corner"
        android:orientation="vertical">
    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/video_title"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="@dimen/feed_item_profile_name"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="@color/background"
            android:paddingStart="@dimen/feed_item_profile_info_padd"
            android:paddingEnd="@dimen/feed_item_profile_info_padd"
            />
    <com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.PlayerView
            android:id="@+id/exo_player_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:show_buffering="true"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: that was my first approach but, I need to put the Exoplayer into a FrameLayout just to have a ImageView as a Thumbnail over it, by clicking it the ExoPlayer starts. That's why the LinearLayout was splitted.

Comment: Putting your TextView into a LinearLayout has nothing to do with that. Unless there was more to the layout than in your question, you were simply wrapping one view inside another.

Comment: So I'm having exactly what you've written over here in my layout, and still, after parsing, the space of the padding ecc. is there. I also tried to set visibility:gone in the XML and than set visibility-visible programmatically when there is a text to display.